# Angular2 Material: Add custom styles to md-checkbox

Tags: angular, styles, parent-child, angular-material2

The only thing I want is to re-write [md-checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/component/checkbox) base width and height.
I do not want to do it permanently for all site, just for one component where I'm added `md-checkbox`

So, here is my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'share/grid/my-component.html'
})

export class MyComponent {}
```

And my-component.html

```
 <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
```

So apparently I have to access child component styles, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer work for your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `/deep/` selector to force your styles down the component tree and into any child components. Place the deep styles in your component's style sheet. Here's an example of overriding material design styles for a button. It should be easy to make the adjustments you need to target the relevant checkbox classes.

```
:host /deep/ {
   .md-button-ripple,
   .md-button-focus-overlay {
      display: none;
   }
 }
```

This should only be used if you're using Emulated ViewEncapsulation (which is the default)

[You can read more about ViewEncapsulation and associated styling techniques in the Angular documentation.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#deep)

Comment: Actually, there is a syntax mistake in your answer, but thank you for the suggestion, I found a right answer in the link you mentioned

Comment: @LuninRoman Ah, I forgot to mention that this was written in SCSS. If you're using raw CSS it would appear that there was an an error. I'm glad that you got things working

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'share/grid/my-component.html',
    styles: [`:host /deep/ .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
                height:15px;
                width:15px;
            }
    `]
})

export class MyComponent {}
```